# searching Time Machine backup data

Tags: macos, time-machine

so I get how to browse of Time Machine data; you can see what your backup's state was at any time.

How do you:

- see what files have changed between two successive backups
- find which backup has the last copy of a particular file, before that file was deleted?

Answer (score 2):

For your first question: see the references to TimeTracker (GUI) and timedog (command line) in [What is Time Machine doing?](https://serverfault.com/questions/9422/what-is-time-machine-doing/39310#39310) on Server Fault.

To find a specific file see [Mac 101: Time Machine](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1427):

> You can also perform a Spotlight search in the Finder to find a file. Simply type the Spotlight search field and use the back arrow to have Time Machine search through your backups to find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the properties of folder and move betwwen times to see differences with help of time machine. I also feel that there is one wizard to see all during varying time periods.

Comment: that's very manual and tedious.