# OS X Time Machine log

Tags: macos, logging, time-machine, time-capsule

How can I find out what really being or was backed up by my Time Machine/Capsule? Is there a log somewhere or perhaps I can throw --verbose somewhere to make sure it gets logged now? I see a 700mb transferring to my TimeCapsule as we speak and I'm not even sure what this is..

Comment: See [searching Time Machine backup data](http://superuser.com/questions/7518/searching-time-machine-backup-data) and/or [Verifying Time Machine backups](http://superuser.com/questions/47628/verifying-time-machine-backups) and/or [What is Time Machine doing?](http://serverfault.com/questions/9422/what-is-time-machine-doing) (over on ServerFault)

Answer (score 3):

You could investigate tmutil's compare option. Or possibly string together `tmutil latestbackup` and a `find` command. `tmutil calculateddrift` might be useful as well.

```
tmutil calculatedrift "`tmutil machinedirectory`" <- bonus recursion points
```

Comment: i just ran this command and it showed me that my last backup was 1.6G yet I really dont know what got copy, how can I find out? I think I'm going ran out of space soon(

Comment: can you provide an example for `find` how would I determinate what changed in my last backup?

Answer (score -1):

Time Machine events are logged to the system log, the process is "backupd" so if you search in Console (or just the log files) you'll see the logs for Time Machine.

Comment: not exactly what I need, I want to know exact files that are being transfere, not just what's there by default (which is nothing) or not much to be exact